# Vuelidate deep nested array of strings

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuelidate

I have data with following structure in my Vue file:

```
data() {
  return {
    formData: {
      name: 'foo',
      objects: [
        {id: 0, name: 'a', props: []},
        {id: 1, name: 'b', props: ['2', '23']},
        {id: 2, name: 'c', props: ['44']},
        {id: 3, name: 'd', props: []}
      ]
    },
    currentObj = null,
    currentPropIndex = null
  }
}
```

The number of objects in the array `objects` is dynamic and so is the `props` array, where string values maybe added and removed. I need to use Vuelidate to validate each and every value of props array in each and every object when it's changed. So I tried this:

```
validations: {
  formData: {
    name: { required, maxLength: maxLength(64) },
    objects: {
      props: {
        $each: {
          required, numeric, maxLength: maxLength(5)
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Computed:

```
propsErrors() {
    const errors = [];
    if ( this.currentObj) {
      // const objIndex = _.findIndex(this.formData.objects, o => o.id === this.currentObj.id)
      if (!this.$v.formData.objects['props'][this.currentPropIndex].$dirty) {
        return errors;
      }
      !this.$v.formData.objects['props'][this.currentPropIndex].maxLength && errors.push('Max 5 digits')
      !this.$v.formData.objects['props'][this.currentPropIndex].required && errors.push('Required')
      !this.$v.formData.objects['props'][this.currentPropIndex].numeric && errors.push('Digits only')
    }
    return errors
  },
```

And my Vuetify text field:

```
<v-text-field single-line flat dense required
  v-model="object.props[index]"
  :error-messages="propsErrors"
  label="Prop"
  height="30"
  @click="setCurrents(protocol, index)"
  @blur="$v.formData.protocolPorts['manual_ports'][index].$touch()"
  @input="$v.formData.protocolPorts['manual_ports'][index].$touch()" />
```

And `setCurrents` only sets the currently edited object and prop index:

```
setCurrents (protocol, index) {
    this.currentObj = protocol;
    this.currentPropIndex = index;
  }
```

Once I test the page and click on the text field, I'm getting this error: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"`

I tried to change `propsErrors` (objIndex is currently commented out in the code above)

```
this.$v.formData.objects[objIndex]['props'][index].maxLength && errors.push('Max 5 digits')
```

Text Field (`oi` stands for object index):

```
@input="$v.formData.objects[oi].props[index].$touch()"
```

And validations:

```
validations: {
  formData: {
    name: { required, maxLength: maxLength(64) },
    objects: {
      required,
      $each: {
        props: {
          $each: {
            required, numeric, maxLength: maxLength(5)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Still keep getting errors. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Looking at your code, the error you're getting means that either object in object.props[index] is undefined or $v.formData.objects[oi] is undefined

Comment: @Shoejep It's in `$v.formData.objects[oi]`. Looks like I'm not targeting something correctly and I can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: Could you show how object and oi are defined?

Comment: @Shoejep Sure: `<v-row  v-for="(object, oi) in formData.objects" :key="object.id"></v-row>`

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Vuelidate but I found this example was quite useful and reasonably similar to what you're trying to do https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation

Your data in the Vue instance should be changed from

```
currentObj = null,
currentPropIndex = null
```

to

```
currentObj: null,
currentPropIndex: null
```

Answer (score 0):

$each is now removed see this https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/781

Comment: what is the alternative for this in vuelidate-next version?